# Getting access to variable inside function

Tags: java, variables, scope

I am positive this has probably been answered many many times but I do not know the words to search for to find the answer.  So here is the question

I'm using java and I have

```
int my_var = 3;

thing.myListener(new Listener() {
    public void onStart(int posistion) {
            my_var <-- I want to get access to my_var
        }
    });
```

How do I get access to `my_var` inside the `onStart` function.  Also what is this type of problem called?  Thanks!

Comment: Besides, I and [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html#naming) recommend you to rename your variable to `myVar` instead of the PHP styled, `my_var`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make it `final`. This is an anonymous inner class.

```
final int my_var = 3;
```

Comment: Can you show your exact code? The approach should work for any type of object.

Comment: If you are working with eclipse, it suggests you do just that automatically.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using global variables. Here is an example:

A simple way to utilize "global" variables in Java is to define a class Global with the desired variables as static members of it:

```
    public class Global {
            public static int x = 37;
            public static String s = "aaa";
    }
```

Such members can be accessed by saying:

```
    public class test {
            public static void main(String args[])
            {
                    Global.x = Global.x + 100;
                    Global.s = "bbb";
            }
    }
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: It's a terrible idea to have global variables. Only constants can be global. If you make variables global, you'll lose thread safety.

Comment: @AlexisK won't be too long before it breaks though :)